# Move 2 circles in opposite directions in SVG

Tags: svg

I want to draw 2 circles in SVG and move them vertically. One in upward direction and the other one in downward direction. How can I do that?

Comment: use two hands, maybe that will work ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   version="1.1"
   width="10cm" height="10cm"
   viewBox="0 0 1000 1000"
   preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
   style="background-color:white; border: solid 1px black;"
>
    <g transform="translate(500,500)">
        <circle id="c" cx="0" cy="0" r="50" fill="red" stroke="red">
            <animate attributeName="cy" from="0" to="-400" start="0s" dur="3s"/>
        </circle>
        <circle id="c" cx="0" cy="0" r="50" fill="green" stroke="green">
            <animate attributeName="cy" from="0" to="400" start="0s" dur="3s"/>
        </circle>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: @tester As @collapsar helped solve your problem, you should 'accept' the answer by clicking the check mark next to this answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow!